# Calculate the battery life of a sensor node

Tags: batteries

I need a way to calculate the battery life of a sensor node given that the current consumption varies. I have a method but need clarification that it is correct.

Sensor uses 3.3v

Sensor consumes: 
80mA for 6s per day,
4mA for 30s per day and
18uA for 86364s per day.

Power consumption per day is calculated:

0.08A*3.3V*6s + 0.004A*3.3V*30s + 0.000018A*3.3V*86364s = 7.110 Ws/day

Battery is 4*1.5V alkaline AAs in series = 4*1.5V*2.5Ah*0.8(converter efficiency) = 12Wh = 43200Ws

43200Ws / 7.110 Ws/day = 6075.949 days = 16.65 years

Can anyone confirm whether this method is correct? Any advice is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I doubt this battery will last 16 years even if not connected to anything.

Comment: Your method seems fine, but depending on the type of battery it has a self discharge rate you have to take into account. Alkaline batteries loose 2-3% per year, lead acid 5% per month, Li-ion 5% the first 24h and then 1-2% per month. The best is probably a lithium primary cell (non rechargeable) with 0.5-2% per year.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating battery life, I personally like to use mAh instead of Watt. This is because the battery voltage will drop with time.

For your case:

1.5V alkaline AAs is 750mAh, so in total is 4x750mAh = 3000mAh.

current per day is (80mA*6s + 4mA*30s + 0.018mA*86364s)/3600 = 0.60mAh/day

so battery life is 3000/0.60/365 = 13.70year